# Add user to MailChimp subscriber list in SWIFT 2

Tags: swift, mailchimp

I am using MailChimp for email marketing service. Now i want to add an user to my subscription list but it says invalid email as JSON response. My code is given below.

```
      var url = "https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe"

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let params = ["apikey":"******************-us4", "id":"*******", "email":["email":email, "euid": "", "leid": ""], "merge_vars":["FNAME": name,"LNAME": ""], "double_optin": "false"]
    request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])


    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard data != nil else {
            print("no data found: \(error)")
            return
        }



        do {
            if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                print("Success: \(String(json))")
    } catch let parseError {
            print(parseError)                                                          // Log the error thrown by `JSONObjectWithData`
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same but working perfect with my mailchimp API. As per mailchimp official documentation ( https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php ) your json format is correct. So ensure the following

1) Make sure your API key is correct.

2) Make sure your List ID is correct.

3) Recheck your network firewall

4) Make sure your email is not existing in the current list.

Comment: thank you for your answer, there is an problem with my List ID.